# How to publish/subscribe or call/register a procedure/event in crossbar.io dynamically at runtime?

Tags: node.js, autobahn, crossbar, wamp-protocol

There are methods in crossbar to publish/subscribe the event or to call/register the procedure but once we write code, its done, suppose I want to publish/register the event/procedure at runtime, then what should be done? is there any way?